# Java decompilers that support renaming and other IDE features

Tags: reverse-engineering, decompiler

I've been trying my hand at decompiling dex and jar files with a few decompilers. So far the best one I've used is jadx, and it also comes with a GUI. However, it seems to be read only. Is there a decompiler that allows me to rename variables/methods/classes for obfuscated code, as well as other more advanced IDE features such as find when a class/method/variable is called/accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to do that is to decompile the JAR and then import the code in a IDE of your choice.

If you use IntelliJ IDEA you can create a new project, import the JAR as an external lib, and then use the built-in decompiler. You can then set breakpoints etc.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up importing the source to Eclipse. It won't compile, but at least I can refactor everything and make it more legible.